# How can I record a drive's volume label at compile time?

Tags: c++, macros

At first, I thought I could just use the __FILE__ macro but it only gives me the drive letter and path of the current file, what I need is something that includes the volume label.

I know I can get the volume label using the [GetVolumeInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364993(v=vs.85).aspx) function but I really need the volume label of a drive on the machine that the code is compiled on. Not necessarily a drive on the machine that the code is run from.

In the end I want to have a string that I can output that will show a volume label that was recorded at compile time. Basically, the same idea as __FILE__ if only it included the volume label with the path. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: You'd probably have to write your own macro and register it with the preprocessor. It doesn't seem like a very portable thing at all.

Comment: Either that or write a script that'd generate that header for you as part of your build step which you'll just include from the code.